# concatenate multiple string columns with a separator in presence of empty value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 
             'fea1':['high', 'med', ''],
             'fea2': ['med', '', 'high'],
             'fea3': ['low', 'high', 'low']})

id  fea1    fea2    fea3
1   high    med     low
2   med             high
3           high    low
```

I need to create a new column `fea` which concatenate columns `fea1`, `fea2`, `fea3` with a separator `/`.  Ignore those empty cells.

```
id  fea1    fea2    fea3    fea
1   high    med     low     high/med/low
2   med             high    med/high
3           high    low     high/low
```

Here is what I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 
             'fea1':['high', 'med', ''],
             'fea2': ['med', '', 'high'],
             'fea3': ['low', 'high', 'low']})
df['fea'] = df['fea1']+'/' + df['fea2']+ '/' +df['fea3']

id  fea1    fea2    fea3    fea
1   high    med     low     high/med/low
2   med             high    med//high
3           high    low     /high/low
```

In row 2 and 3, I have unwanted extra `/`.  Does anyone know how to concatenate the columns without creating these extra separators `/` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the `/` at the start and in the middle of your column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 
             'fea1':['high', 'med', ''],
             'fea2': ['med', '', 'high'],
             'fea3': ['low', 'high', 'low']})
df['Column'] = df[[x for x in df.columns.drop('id')]].apply(lambda x : '/'.join(x), axis = 1).str.replace('//', '/').str.strip('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

using apply and regex to remove leading "/"

```
df['fea'] = df[['fea1','fea2','fea3']].apply(lambda x: "/".join(x.str.strip()), axis=1).replace(r'^/','', regex=True)
df
```

```
    id  fea1    fea2    fea3    fea
0   1   high    med     low     high/med/low
1   2   med             high    med//high
2   3           high    low     high/low
```